# Getting segmentation fault if size of two dimensional array is too big

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

I listed the code below. If I define `ARR_SIZE` too much (for example 820), I get a **segmentation fault** error. But if `ARR_SIZE` is not so big (320, for example), the code works.

***GDB*** shows an error just in `int main()`.

I think the problem is in initialization phase during the two dimensional arrays, but not sure.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "time.h"
#include "stdint.h"


#define ARR_SIZE 820
#define TICK(X) clock_t X = clock()
#define TOCK(X) printf("time %s: %g sec.\n", (#X), (double)(clock() - (X)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC)

void copyji(int src[ARR_SIZE][ARR_SIZE], int dst[ARR_SIZE][ARR_SIZE]){
    int i, j;
    for (j = 0; j < ARR_SIZE; j++)
        for (i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
            dst[i][j] = src[i][j];
}

void copyij(int src[ARR_SIZE][ARR_SIZE], int dst[ARR_SIZE][ARR_SIZE]){
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < ARR_SIZE; j++)
                dst[i][j] = src[i][j];
}


int main(){
    int srcArr1[ARR_SIZE][ARR_SIZE];
    int srcArr2[ARR_SIZE][ARR_SIZE];
    int dstArr1[ARR_SIZE][ARR_SIZE];
    int dstArr2[ARR_SIZE][ARR_SIZE];
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < ARR_SIZE; j++){
            srcArr1[i][j] = i - j;
            srcArr2[i][j] = j - i;
        }

    TICK(TIME_JI);
    copyji(srcArr1, dstArr1);
    TOCK(TIME_JI);

    TICK(TIME_IJ);
    copyij(srcArr2, dstArr2);
    TOCK(TIME_IJ);


    return 1;
}
```

Comment: All your arrays are placed on the program stack in the stack frame for `main`. Without issuing some sort of syscall to expand it, there is a _limited_ amount of stack space you can have (e.g. 8MB).

Place your arrays in global/file scope and this limitation is removed.

Comment: You're using too much stack to pass parameter by value to the function `copyij`! You have to pass the parameters by reference (pointers) or you have to use global variables.

Comment: @SirJoBlack Function parameters never have array type. They actually are passing by pointer, not by value. The trouble here is probably only with the variables in `main`.

Comment: automatic variables like your srcArr1 and so on allocate on the stack which mostly is very limited. You need to instead use the heap when you allocate memory.

Comment: @aschepler. You have reason :p ... The problem shall be the BIG declaration into the main scope. :p ...

Comment: Please, **write functions as functions** and do not abuse the macro system. This makes your code really difficult to follow for no reason since those aren't functions, and worse, they can't be stepped into in a debugger. You're making this code far more miserable to work with than is necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You 're getting this fault because your code causes stack overflow for big arrays size e.g 820 while for smaller size not. You could declare your arrays with **`malloc`**.

Example using malloc:

```
int **srcArr1 = (int **)malloc(ARR_SIZE * sizeof(int *));
for (i=0; i<ARR_SIZE; i++) 
         srcArr1[i] = (int *)malloc(ARR_SIZE * sizeof(int));
```

With malloc you are dynamically allocating memory using heap not stack, so this will not lead to seg. fault.

Another workaround would be to declare your arrays globally or static this also allocates memory from heap not stack.

Comment: Maybe make the arrays `static` or global instead - more of a short-term solution, but it avoids doubts and complications related to `malloc`.

Comment: @coder, Thank you, this solution has solved my problem. As i understand, in the for loop it should be srcArr1 instead of arr.